# Storing a Remote File Locally Using C

Tags: c, rsync

We currently have code that is in place written in C where I have to add my logic in obtaining proof of concept of the evidence of particular content in a file. So what I am trying to accomplish is:

1 - Downloading this file (/etc/vpnc/test.conf) from a remote machine to a temp file(locally)

2 - Searching for something juicy to display showing the proof is in the pudding.
ex. /etc/vpnc/test.conf

```
IPSec ID TestID
IPSec gateway blah.blah.com 
IPSec secret 123456
Xauth username blah_user
Xauth password 123456!
IKE Authmode psk
#IKE DH Group dh2
#NAT Traversal Mode cisco-udp
Local Port 10000
DPD idle timeout (our side) 0
```

3 - Finally, simply printing out my findings to stdout using already custom functions already in place.ex:

```
Xauth username blah_user
```

Someone else had suggested using tmpnam and or mkstemp functions

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    char buf[4096];
    char *n=tmpnam(NULL); // Use this as the file name, not tmp_file.

 // get the file
  ... 

    FILE *fp=fopen(n, "r");
    unlink(n);
    // Read a line into 'buf' until we run out of lines
    while(fgets(buf, 4096, fp))
    {
            // Check the contents of 'buf' for what you want
    }
}
```

but my lack of knowing C has slowed me down. So looking at the code above, how do I get the results of:
Code:

```
 rsync rsync://192.168.3.1/vpnc/test.conf
```

into the "n" temp file? Forgive me for my stupidity.I promise I will grab a C book to stop nagging the forum

Comment: Grab the C book now and nag the forum later.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way:

```
char cmd[200];
sprintf(cmd,"rsync rsync://192.168.3.1/vpnc/test.conf %s",n);
system(cmd);
FILE *fp=fopen(n, "r");
```

I have made the assumption that tmpnam will return a sufficientl short filename containing no special characters. typically these names are only 10 characters or so, so it should easily fit in `char cmd[200]` along with the rest of the command.